# Categories and Keywords access via Razor Template in Tridion

Tags: razor, tridion

I am attempting to access values in the Categories and Keywords information for a Tridion Publication via a Razor TBB in Tridion 2011. The Razor documentation lists the following example code:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var keyword in Publication.MetaData.SomeKeywordFields) {
<li>@keyword.Title (@keyword.Id)</li>
}
</ul>
```

I have a Keyword inside of a Category though... in fact, that's the only way I am myself aware that you can even have a Keyword in Tridion, but correct me if I am wrong. Extrapolating from the example's syntax, I tried the following where "myCategory" is a Category in the publication, and "myKeyword" is a Keyword inside of the myCategory Category:

```
@foreach (var keyword in Publication.MetaData.myCategory) {
if(@keyword.Title == "myKeyword") {
@keyword.Title
}
```

When I run this template, I get an error stating that DynamicItemsFields: Key 'testcategory' Not Found In ItemFields (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Can anyone help with identifying if it is even possible to do what I am attempting here (as it seems like it is based on the documentation but still not sure) and if so, provide an example of the correct syntax?

Comment: A Component or Metadata field that refers to a Category is typically called a Keyword field, since the values that you select in such a field are Keywords. It looks like your Publication Metadata does not have a field called testCategory/myCategory.

Comment: Seems that you haven't joined in **[Tridion - Area51 - StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=DQG1rvz454qNn9xqeeO2NA2)**. Currently proposal is in **Commit** state and you can be part of it by clicking the link.

Comment: Thanks for the invite. I have joined and will post Tridion threads there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with your code except that you're using the actual CategoryName. As Puf commented, you have to use the "fieldname" of you Publication Metadata not the actual CategoryName. You should just change the "myCategory" to the actual fieldname

```
@foreach (var keyword in Publication.MetaData.*<<FIELDNAME>>*) {
   if(@keyword.Title == "myKeyword") {
        @keyword.Title
   }
}
```

[FIELDNAME] --> is the XMLName of publication metadata schema.

Comment: I did have the XMLName field in the Category item "myCategory" as both the Name and XMLName are "myCategory". Do I need to check the box that says "Use for identification" too?

I also do not see an XMLName field for the myKeyword item, is there some logic missing here for telling the template to process each child node of the category?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong place.. You need to look at your metadata schema definition (design tab) and use the XMLName of the field.

Comment: In the Category, I have a General, Security, and Info tab. There isn't a metadata tab directly on the Category. I apologize, but I've never used a Category/Keyword in this manner before... I must be missing a step in how I am defining the category. I just made it by using the GUI to right-click and add new Category to the Category and Keywords object. Is there another step?

Comment: You're still looking at the wrong place. You need to check your SCHEMA not the Category. Go to the Schemas Publication  and check your Metadata schema.

Comment: I was hoping that I could access the Categories and Keywords objects from the Publication rather than having to define it as part of the metadata schema for the Page. Should I make a metadata schema for the Publication at the 010 level? How would I apply that?

Comment: Looks like some conusion here. let's start baby steps. Couple of Questions: 1. First of all, Do you have metadata schema in place? 2. Did you have the Publication Metadata at the you web site publication?

Comment: I have a page metadata schema for the page. I have not set up a publication metadata schema, though the implementation was originally produced by an outside contractor, so they may have made one. Where would I look for that if there is one? If there isn't one, how do I attach metadata to a publication? At the root level 010, or at the publication to production level at 050?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12449/discussion-between-ram-g-and-user1408652)

Answer (score 1):

Keywords are indeed always within a Category or another Keyword. But they are used within items like Components and (as in the example) metadata on Publications, Folders, etc.

The example from the documentation is outputting each value of a multi-valued metadata Keyword field on the Publication (i.e. "Allow Multiple Values", "Values selected from a list" and "Category" all checked in the Metadata Schema).

If you are trying to do something similar, you can indeed modify the name of the field and it will work. From your question, however, it seems like you are trying to loop over all Keywords within a certain Category - which requires a different approach.

For that, you would need the equivalent of a GetList call within your TBB. I'm not familiar enough with the Razor mediator to provide sample code for that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ram G in chat:

The Publication itself, typically your 010, 020... 050 etc. levels, can have a metadata schema attached to them as well. The XMLName of the field being targeted by the Razor logic block above is actually the field name of this metadata schema item, not the name of the Category itself. In the metadata schema for the publication, if you select the Design tab, Make your XML field for the item a "Text" type, select "Options will be selected from a list", by default, another Checkbox will appear called "Category" which, if checked, automatically pulls in the full list of Category items present in that publication. So, when that Field is targeted by the Razor logic now, it is in multiple steps targeting the Category value as well.

Thanks again Ram G